# Идеи простых веб-приложений для тренировки

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby, sinatra

Недавно начал изучать sinatra, но не могу ничего придумать, что можно было бы написать для тренировки. Хеллоуворлды и т.п. - слишком банально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например фото галерею. Чтобы не искать фотки, можно взять их из фликра, при помощи API (тоже тренировка). Ну и в таком духе, ещё можно сделать свой маленький твитер, опять же у твитера есть API.

Также частенько делаю те же самые задачи, что и на работе, только другими инструментами.

Comment: [![placehold.it](http://placehold.it/100x50&text=PLACEHOLD.IT)](http://placehold.it/)

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте приложение для себя. То которого вам не хватало. Простенькое.

[Бонус](https://github.com/sausheong) как изучающему синатру. У этого парня в гитхабе есть примеры.

Comment: За линк спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

CMS.

Правда такие тренировки могут привести к серьёзным проектам, но это уже...